# Spring Data Neo4j 4 and Pageable vs repository method ORDER BY parameters

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

```
@Query("MATCH (parentD:Decision)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {parentDecisionId} RETURN childD, ru, u ORDER BY childD.createDate DESC")
List<Decision> getChildDecisions(@Param("parentDecisionId") Long parentDecisionId);
```

Is it possible to pass order expression like `childD.createDate` and order direction like `ASC` or `DESC` via Spring Data Neo4j 4 repository method parameters ? If so, could you please show an example.

Or do I need to use `Pageable` in this case ?

Comment: Referring to your first question I found this post (look at the answer): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392784/spring-data-neo4j-order-by-order-fails - This would mean that it is not possible to use your order direction as a method parameter.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Data Neo4j - ORDER BY {order} fails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39392784/spring-data-neo4j-order-by-order-fails)