# SDN4, Neo4j OGM @QueryResult Session.query and Pagable

Tags: cypher, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4, neo4j-ogm

Right now due to an open GitHub issue https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/215 in Neo4j OGM I have to use a following workaround in order to convert `org.neo4j.ogm.session.Session.query` result that returns `@QueryResult` into List of this `@QueryResult`:

Example Cypher query:

```
 MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId}  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH childD, ru, u, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight  OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue375:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic375:Characteristic) WHERE id(sortCharacteristic375) = 375 RETURN childD AS decision, ru, u, toFloat(sum(weight)) as weight, sortValue375 ORDER BY weight DESC, sortValue375.value DESC, childD.createDate DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 1000
```

Workaround:

```
@QueryResult
public class WeightedDecision {

    private Decision decision;

    private Double weight;

...
}

Result queryResult = session.query(characteristicCypher, parameters);

List<WeightedDecision> weightedDecisions = new ArrayList<>();

for (Map<String, Object> result : queryResult) {
    WeightedDecision weightedDecision = new WeightedDecision();
    weightedDecision.setDecision((Decision) result.get("decision"));
    weightedDecision.setWeight((double) result.get("weight"));
    weightedDecisions.add(weightedDecision);
}
```

Right now instead of `List<WeightedDecision>` I have to return `Page<WeightedDecision>`

How it can be done ? Please help me to change the code in order to translate queryResult into `Page<WeightedDecision>`

Also, how to provide a `countQuery` in this logic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to this post [Conversion of List to Page in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749559/conversion-of-list-to-page-in-spring) you can to the mapping from a resulting list to a `Page` instance with the `org.springframework.data.domain.PageImpl` implementation. In your case, after mapping the result to a List you can do following:

```
PageRequest pageable = new PageRequest(0, 2);
Page<WeightedDecision> page = new PageImpl<>(weightedDecisions, pageable, weightedDecisions.size());
```

Background: As far as I know in this moment it is not possible to use Pageable on custom queries in SDN ([Paging and sorting in Spring Data Neo4j 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30624435/paging-and-sorting-in-spring-data-neo4j-4)). Therefore you have to do the mapping on your own.

Your second question abount a count logic. In my opinion you have to call your query a second time with changes depending on what you want to count. For example to count the `childD` nodes:

```
MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision)-[ru:CREATED_BY]->(u:User) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId}  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH childD, ru, u, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight  
OPTIONAL MATCH (childD)<-[:SET_FOR]->(sortValue375:Value)-[:SET_ON]->(sortCharacteristic375:Characteristic) WHERE id(sortCharacteristic375) = 375 RETURN count(childD) AS result;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it okay to translate for example new PageRequest(0, 1000) into SKIP 0 LIMIT 1000 or I should do a some math on PageRequest.page, PageRequest.size params before translate it into the corresponding Cypher SKIP and LIMIT ?

Comment: It depends on what you want with the page. If your only task is to return a page instead of a list then it would be ok to use skip and limit in your query and put the full resulting data in the page object.

Comment: Thanks for your help !